# Backbone View Rendering and refreshes page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am still learning Backbone and have searched the entire day. I have a few views in my Page:
The Employee View:

```
var EmployeeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options){

        this.bus = options.bus;
        this.model.on("onChange", this.render, this);
        this.bind("venueSelected", this.model);
        this.updateButton = $("#employeeUpdate");
    },
    setup: function () {
        var self= this;
        this.get('data').on('change', function () {
            self.trigger("change");
        })},
    attributes : function () {
        // Return model data
        return {
            id : this.model.get("Id")
        }},
    events: {
        "click #employeeDelete": "onClickDelete",
        "click #employeeUpdate": "onClickUpdate",
        "click #employeeDetails": "onClickDetails"
    },
    onClickDetails: function(model){
        this.bus.trigger("venueSelected", this.model);
    },
    onClickUpdate: function(e, model){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(e.currentTarget).attr("disabled", "true");
        //$('span[id*=updateBtn]').attr("disabled", "true");
        $("button.upd").attr("disabled", true);

        var updateEmployee = new UpdateEmployeeView({model: this.model, bus: this.bus});
        updateEmployee.render();
    },
    onClickDelete: function(){
        this.model.destroy();
        },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.attr("id", this.model.Id);

        this.$el.html("<div row style='width:100%;'><div class='col-sm-12 liRowMargin'>" +this.model.get("Name") + "<button id='employeeDetails' class='btn-primary btnFloat'>Details</button>" + "<button id='employeeDelete' class='btn-primary btnFloat'>Delete</button>" + "<button id='employeeUpdate' class='upd btn-primary btnFloat'>Update</button>" + "</div>");
        return this;
    }
});
```

The EmployeesView:

```
var EmployeesView = Backbone.View.extend({

    id: "employees",
    el: "#employeeList",

    initialize: function(options){
        this.options = options;
        if (!(options && options.model))
            throw new Error("model is not specified.");

        this.bus = options.bus;
        this.model.on("add", this.onAddEmployee, this);
        this.model.on("remove", this.onRemoveEmployee, this);
        this.bus.on("onAddEmployee", this.onAddEmployee, this);
    },
    onRemoveEmployee: function(employee){
        this.$("li#" + employee.get("Id")).remove();
    },
    onAddEmployee: function(employee){

        employee.save();
       var view = new EmployeeView({model: employee, bus: this.bus});
       this.$el.append(view.render().$el);
    },
    render: function(){
        var self = this;

        this.model.each(function(employee){
        var view = new EmployeeView({ model: employee, bus: self.bus });
        self.$el.append(view.render().$el);
        });

        return this;
    }
});
```

The AddRender View which I use to call another view on an event click:

```
var AddRender = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#newEmployee",
    id: "addRender",

    initialize: function(options){
        this.options = options;
        this.bus = options.bus;
    },
    events: {
        "click #btnNewEmployee": "OnClickNewEmployee"
    },
    OnClickNewEmployee: function(){

        var addEmployee = new AddNewEmployee({ bus : this.bus});
        addEmployee.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.append("<button id='btnNewEmployee'>Add Employee</button>");
    }
});
```

Then the `AddNewEmployeeView` which is supposed to be used to add new employees :

```
var AddNewEmployee = Backbone.View.extend({

    id: "addingNewEmployee",
    el: "#newEmployeeAdd",

    initialize: function(options){
        this.options = options;
        this.bus = options.bus;
    },
    events: {
        "click #addNewEmployeeClick": "onClickAddNewEmployee"
    },
    onClickAddNewEmployee: function(){

        var employee = new Employee();
        employee.set('Name', $('#name').val());
        employee.set('KnownAs', $('#knownas').val());
        employee.set('Surname', $('#surname').val());
        employee.set('ContactNumber', $('#contactNumber').val());
        employee.set('Position', $('#position').val());

        //this.bus.trigger("onAddEmployee", employee);

        $("#name").val("");
        $("#knownAs").val("");
        $("#surname").val("");
        $("#contactNumber").val("");
        $("#position").val("");
        $("#name").focus();

        //this.$el.unbind();
        //this.$el.empty();
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log("Rendered Entry Point");
        this.$el.append("<label>Name:</label><input type='text' autofocus id='name'/>");
        console.log("Rendered");

        return this;
    }
});
```

The challenge I am facing is that when ever I call the `OnClickNewEmployee` event from the `addRender` View to display the `AddNewEmployee` View, the `AddNewEmployee` View flashes and the entire page refreshes, I have seen that there is no event called after a page renders in Backbone but I am puzzled by what makes my page to refresh

Comment: try event.preventDefault()

Comment: How is the event triggered? From what element? Maybe you should remove all other views and try with just the view having element and it's template, and share that minimal code